# How to get the ROW NUMBER base on Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How in Google Sheet, I can get the row number based on QUERY.

Col A, I have:

```
=QUERY(Datas!A:A; "select A WHERE A LIKE 'Test'"))
```

How in Col B, I can have the **row number** where this result comes from ?

So for example, if the query result a result from the line #9, it should gave me 9.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Add an Additional Column with Filter() and Row()

You just need to create a 2 column formula with your current query formula placed on the first column. On the second formula, you should use `Row()` to get the row number and `Filter()` to filter out the raw data based on your required search word (in this case, "Test").

Your formula should look like this:

```
={QUERY(Datas!A:A; "select A WHERE A LIKE 'Test'")\FILTER(ROW(Datas!A:A); Datas!A:A="Test")}
```

### Output:

From this sample data (from 'Datas' sheet):

[image]

The formula will produce the following output:

[image]

### For Regular Expressions:

To add the `LIKE` concept to the formula, you may use `REGEXMATCH()`. This will filter your data based on your regular expression.

Your new function should look like this:

```
={ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(Datas!A:A; "select A WHERE A LIKE '%FR SPORTS | TV%'"); "tvg-name=(.*)tvg-logo");"""";""))\FILTER(ROW(Datas!A:A); REGEXMATCH(Datas!A:A; "FR SPORTS | TV"))}
```

### New Output:

[image]

Comment: Can the last part support something like `LIKE` ?
`Datas!A:A="Test"`

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data? From what I know, you can use regular expressions in the conditional statement.

Comment: This is my example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MqDnkMvfC5URENg7MUnHC7cuHpPtkNYhN25TzfpiZIg/edit#gid=2113905641

It's on the Col B, where I would like the row number.
Don't know if it helps.

Comment: You should have the write rights.

Comment: let me look into it.

Comment: Kindly check the For Regular Expressions section if the new formula suits your request.

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if you feel that it was useful to you.

Comment: Ho wow. Perfectly what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can stack the row numbers in the first argument and select them in the query.

```cpp
=QUERY({ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(Datas!A:A))\Datas!A:A}; "select Col2, Col1 WHERE Col2 LIKE 'Test'"))
```